# CassandraPojoSink no error, however data is not getting written into the cassandra

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to write Flink's Cassandra SINK connector using **CassandraPojoSink** class. I am not getting any error/exception, but No records committed into the Cassandra table.

I am using following code.

========= **Sink connector code snapshot** ==================

```
DataStream<Event> stream = eventStream.flatMap(new EventTransformation());

    try {
        stream.addSink(new CassandraPojoSink<>(Event.class, new ClusterBuilder() {

          private static final long serialVersionUID = -2485105213096858846L;

          @Override
          public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
            return builder.addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(9042).build();
         }
        }));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

====== **POJO CLASS** ================

```
@Table(keyspace= "cloud", name = "event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3284839826384795926L;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "msg")
        private String msg;

    public Event(){

    }

    //......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why a Flink job might fail to produce any output. Some common reasons include:

- the app doesn't call env.execute()
- the app is set to use event time, but there's no watermark generator
- the watermarking logic is confused somehow, and no watermarks are being generated (e.g., the app is generating watermarks based on the CPU clock rather than event timestamps, causing every event to be late)

Answer (score 0):

On changing POJO to Tuple, adding timestamp watermarks code is working perfectly.
I am able to see my data is written into the Cassandra database.

DataStream> events = event_stream.flatMap(new EventTransformation()).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                                    new AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks>() {

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final long maxOutOfOrderness = 1_000L; // 1
        // second
        private long currentMaxTimestamp = 0;

        @Override
        public long extractTimestamp(Tuple3<String, String, Long> arg0,
                                            long arg1) {
                long timestamp = arg0.f3; // get
                currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(timestamp, currentMaxTimestamp);
                return timestamp;
        }

        @Override
        public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
            return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness);
        }
    });

                event_stream.addSink(new CassandraTupleSink<Tuple3<String, String, Long>("INSERT INTO cloud.condition (name, msg, time) VALUES (?,?,?);", new ClusterBuilder() {

                            /**
                             * 
                             */
                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            protected Cluster buildCluster(Builder builder) {
                                return builder.addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(9042).build();
                            }
                        }));

                env.setParallelism(2);

                env.execute();
```